# How do we organize the reducer function in Redux that is returning cloned nested state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a reducer file like this:

```
const initialState = {
  name: '',
  address: { street: '', city: '', country: '' },
  phone: {cell: '', home: ''},
  contacts: {family: [], friends: []}
};

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_NAME':
      return {...state, address: {...state.address}, phone: {...state.phone}, contacts: contacts: {family: [...obj.contacts.family], friends: [...obj.contacts.friends]}};
  }
}
```

As you can imagine I will be cloning the nested object in every single switch case, making the code hard to read. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "spread" `...` syntax will include a shallow copy of the object you're expanding.  Usually this is enough, especially in Redux, where you shouldn't be mutating the state object after you create it.  So your reducer function can just be

```javascript
const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_NAME':
      return { ...state, name: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

which in turn is equivalent to

```javascript
case 'SET_NAME':
  return {
    // name: state.name,
    address: state.address,
    phone: state.phone,
    contacts: state.contacts,
    name: action.payload
  };
```

The old state and new state will share the nested objects (you will not get a deep copy), but that's okay.

(If your objects are "meaty" enough, also consider Redux's [reducer composition](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#splitting-reducers), which lets you write a separate reducer for each of these subfields and combine them together.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @David Maze.
While it is usually fine to use spread, it gets over-complicated, harder to read and easier to make errors. I've faced that in my work already.

I strongly recommend splitting the state in smaller reducer functions, each of them taking care of the props of the current state. You will avoid nesting of objects and your code will look cleaner.